# How to execute a second plan, when the first fail in qwery, in JASON AgnetSpeak

Tags: agent, multi-agent

I have a little problem with my program, in one secction one agent X send a `tell` to the agent Y, and this agent, checks his belief base to verify the fact, the problem is when the plan fails, he tried adding a `-plan` but its not worked, I appreciate any help, I have changed the context of the problem so that it is better understood, but the main idea is the same

```
/* Initial beliefs and rules */
```

wedding_guests(john).
wedding_guests(anna).
wedding_guests(bob).
wedding_guests(ed).

/* Initial goals */

/* Plans */

+I_can_enter(R)[source(Ag)]  <-
?wedding_guests(R)
.print(R,"You are on the guest list")
riesgo2.

-I_can_enter(R) <-
.print("You can not pass").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

failure plans can be used only for goals and, in your case, the plan `+i_can_enter...` reacts to new beliefs and not new goals. The plan `-i_can_enter....` reacts to the deletion of such belief. (note that the lower case in `i_can_enter`, otherwise it is a variable.)

There are many ways to solve your problem:

1. use the performative `achieve` instead of `tell`, so that the receiver will have a new goal instead of a new belief. The plan then could be `+!i_can_enter(R) ...` with the plan failure being `-!i_can_enter(R) ...`.
2. place the test in the context of the plan:

```
+i_can_enter(R)[source(Ag)] : wedding_guests(R) <- .print(R,"You are on the guest list").

+i_can_enter(R) <- .print("You can not pass").
```

3. use `askOne` performative. In the receiver:

```
+?can_enter(R,ok) : wedding_guests(R). // R can enter if it is a wedding guest
+?can_enter(R,nok).                    // R cannot otherwise
```

in the sender:

```
.send(receiver_name, askOne, can_enter(john,_), can_enter(_,ok)); // only continue if answer is "ok"
```

or

```
.send(receiver_name, askOne, can_enter(john,_), can_enter(_,A));
.print("it is ",A," for john to enter");
```

The forth term in the .send unifies with the answer.

Comment: Thankyou, now understand the contxt of plans, it is very useful!